# symfony user login within ldap or fos_userbundle depending the user

Tags: symfony, ldap, fosuserbundle

Is it possible to have two kind of login depending on which user is submitting a login?

Some user using an LDAP server and other using the standard fosuser login mechanism.

I tried to use the chain_provider option.

```
security:
encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\LdapUser: plaintext
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: plaintext
providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [fr3d_ldapbundle,fos_userbundle]
        fr3d_ldapbundle:
            id: fr3d_ldap.security.user.provider
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        logout_on_user_change: true

        pattern:    ^/

        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /profile
            check_path: fos_user_security_check

        fr3d_ldap:
            provider: ~

        logout:     true
        anonymous:  true

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

but I get

```
Not configuring explicitly the provider for the "fr3d_ldap" listener on "main" firewall is ambiguous as there is more than one registered provider.
```

Comment: Maybe you would like to take a look here: https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle

Comment: @FrankB Great comment! thanks

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using for this project? Since Symfony 2.8 there is a [LDAP component](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-ldap-component). You can find more about it in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/ldap.html).